# Tridion 2013 SP1 publishing issue (DXA)

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, publishing, dxa-1.7

We are using .NET version of DXA 1.7. While publishing theme.zip, we are getting below error. I'm not seeing any specific error. Please suggest

> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure
> "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_GETLISTCOMPONENTTEMPLATES".

Comment: Is that MSSQL or Oracle database? sometime it could be due to timeout. Did you try the database maintenance scripts and like sp_updatestats and re-index and try again to see this issue goes away or not?  recently Is there any database migration that happened backup and restores activities if any?

Comment: Enable deployer to debug/trace logs to look at the error message in details what is going on?

Comment: Please check the Tridion Event Log for more details about this error.

Comment: BTW: DXA 1.7 officially doesn’t support 2013 SP1. See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/README.md